# PHP image headers and JavaScript loading 

Tags: php, javascript, http-headers

I have big problem with displaying images in fancybox.
Images are "generated" by PHP with `header()` and `readfile()`.

When I access script directly from browser everything is ok, but when request comes from fancybox JavaScript suddenly browser stop responding and after long time in load content area I get binary code instead of image.

Here is the code:

```
ob_clean();
header('Content-Type: '.$post->post_mime_type);

$name = basename($post->guid);
$base = home_url();
$path= $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.str_replace($base,'',$post->guid);
header ('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.$name);
header ('Content-length: ' .filesize($path));
readfile($path);
```

Screen of content loaded into fancybox: http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/8535/screenq.png

Comment: Does this happen in all browser? Try using the Firebug addon to firefox and look at the Net tab to examine what exactly is being sent to the browser when requested by fancybox

Comment: This is very strange, headers looks good for me: http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/1300/jsheader.png

Comment: Agreed - they look correct. The only thing I can think is that fancybox is attempting to guess the image type based on the filename - since you're serving it from a re-written url (at least if I'm reading your screenshot correctly), there's no filename component. For the sake of testing, can you change the url syntax to be `<blah>/f5/f5.png` ?

Comment: Thats the problem, this is Wordpress attachment page, this script is for serving only image when request is from fancybox and normal html for direct requests done with if(!$_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] == 'XMLHttpRequest') so changing url is very hard. I tried with header('Location: xxx); but this doesn't work either

Comment: Ok, we're running out of options here but let's see if we can come up with something that will work... Firstly, does this happen on all browsers?

Comment: Oh and just to eliminate fancybox - if you point it at an image url on the same server (not coming from your php at all) does it work?

Comment: Yes, Only chrome and opera can display this binary data, firefox crashes so as IE, not tested on safari. 

Site is running on my computer but You can visit it, http://91.193.211.226/galeria/femespik/ (BETA ;] )

Comment: and yes, fancybox works fine, before this idea with link to attachment page all links was directed to single image file and everything was ok.

Comment: Basiclife - You were right, fancybox is trying to guess content type by href, I need to dive into JS :) Thanks :)

Comment: Did you change fancybox source code?

Answer (score 1):

The first 4 bytes of the output looks like a valid PNG header.

Please verify that $post->post_mime_type is "image/png".

I don't know the framework, it could get confused by the uncommon "Content-Disposition: inline" header, please delete that line.

Comment: mime types are correct, as I said when script is accessed directly from address bar everything is ok. Screen of Chrome header information from DIRECT NOT JS access http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/7695/headersa.png 

Getting rid of Content-Disposition doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

Found this on http://fancybox.net/faq

> FancyBox gueses content type from url but sometimes it can be wrong. The solution is to force >your type, like so - $(".selector").fancybox({'type' : 'image'});
>   (required version 1.3+)